# letter replacement according to given rules

Tags: javascript

There is a list of rules. The rules specify how to change the word entered. The screenshot shows an example of how the program should work. The result should be a string "aBct". I don't understand how to do this.

```js
function pushRules(list){
    var rules = "";
    var w1 = document.getElementById('inputw1').value;
    var w2 = document.getElementById('inputw2').value;
    var w = w1+'-->'+w2;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var rule = document.createTextNode(w);
    li.appendChild(rule);
}

function applyRule() {
    var str = document.getElementById('inputString').value;
    var numRule = document.getElementById('inputNumRules').value;

    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
      // ...
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="addRules">
    <h3>Add Rules</h3>
    <form>
        <label>w1:</label><input id="inputw1" type="text"><label> --> w2:</label><input id="inputw2" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="pushRules()">
    </form>
    <h3>Rules:</h3>
    <div class="container_rules">
        <ui id="list"></ui>
    </div>
</div>

<h3>Input string</h3>
<input type="text" id="inputString">
<form>
    <p>Apply the selected rule to the symbol at number:</p><input type="text" id="inputNumRules" value="0">
    <input type="button" value="Apply rule" onclick="applyRule()">
</form>
<h3>Result</h3>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution.

Just insert rules and then write the number of rule you want to apply starting from 0

```js
var changeStringFromRules = [];
        var changeStringToRules = [];

        function pushRules(list){
            var rules = "";
            var w1 = document.getElementById('inputw1').value;
            changeStringFromRules.push(w1);
            var w2 = document.getElementById('inputw2').value;
            changeStringToRules.push(w2);
            var w = w1+'-->'+w2;
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var rule = document.createTextNode(w);
            li.appendChild(rule);
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
        }

        function applyRule() {
            var str = document.getElementById('inputString').value;
            var numRule = parseInt(document.getElementById('inputNumRules').value);

            if(str.indexOf(changeStringFromRules[numRule])!== -1){
                str = str.replace(changeStringFromRules[numRule], changeStringToRules[numRule]);
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
        }
```

```html
<div class="addRules">
    <h3>Add Rules</h3>
    <form>
        <label>w1:</label><input id="inputw1" type="text"><label> --> w2:</label><input id="inputw2" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="pushRules()">
    </form>
    <h3>Rules:</h3>
    <div class="container_rules">
        <ui id="list"></ui>
    </div>
</div>

<h3>Input string</h3>
<input type="text" id="inputString">
<form>
    <p>Apply the selected rule to the symbol at number:</p><input type="text" id="inputNumRules" value="0">
    <input type="button" value="Apply rule" onclick="applyRule()">
</form>
<h3>Result</h3>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, You just have to replace few characters in the input string with other characters.

You can use **[replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method.

So all you have to do is,

```
"aBcah".replace(/ah/g,'t');
```

This means, replace all occurrences of *ah* with *t* in the string **aBcah**.

I have used a regex here and /g means to remove all(global flag), without it, it will only remove the first occurrence.

```js
var a = "aBcah".replace(/ah/g,'t');
console.log(a);
```